# Modifying the session data from inside the socket.io callback

Tags: session, node.js, express

I am currently using this stack expres, socket.io, sessionstore. I followed the article here http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/.
Well the problem is that i cannot modify the session values in socket.io callback.

Access from express side works well, the item get increased after each refresh.

```
app.get('/mysession', function(req, res) {
  req.session.item++;
  console.log(req.session);

  res.render('session.jade', {
    title: 'Sample title'
  });
});
```

Using in socket.io side it does not and here is the problem, maybe i am setting the wrong object.

```
var io = io.listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var handshake = socket.handshake;
  onlineCount++;
  console.log('Well done id %s', handshake.sessionID);
  handshake.session.item++;

  console.log(handshake.session);

});
```

Here is bridge code.

```
io.set('authorization', function(data, accept) {
  if (data.headers.cookie) {
    data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
    data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
    sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
      if (err || !session) {
        accept('Error', false);
      } else {
        data.session = session;
        accept(null, true);
      }
    });
  } else {
    return accept('No cookie tansmitted', false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to make this work is to grab the cookie from the request object on the `connect` event, parse it with your favourite cookie parser (I use `connect.utils.parseCookie`), and set it on that socket so that I may access it in future events:

```
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
  var cookie = client.request.headers.cookie;
  var pcookie = connect.utils.parseCookie(cookie);
  var session_id = pcookie["connect.sid"];
  if (session_id) {
    sessionStore.get(session_id, function(err, sess) {
      // do whatever you want with sess here
      // ...
      // if you want to "save" the session for future events
      client.set('session_id', session_id);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sessionStore` API changed a little bit, now its `sessionStore.load(sessionId, cb)` instead of `.get`.